# Job with CVS respository cannot be loaded

Tags: jenkins, cvs, jenkins-plugins

I configured a job using CVS. The configuration is pretty standard:

```
type: "Free Style"-Softwareprojekt
CVSROOT: :pserver:cvs@192.168.xyz.xyz:/home/cvs/cvsroot
Connection uses a password: box checked and password provided.
Location: Head
Project name: myproject
```

The job is running fine - means it checksout the project from CVS repository into the workspace. However, after restarting jenkins loading jobs, that have a CVS respository configured, fails: (don't even showup in the jenkins web gui)

```
SEVERE: Failed Loading job TestCVS
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.scm.CVSSCM.getCvsRoot()Ljava/lang/String;
        at hudson.plugins.javanet.StatsProperty.getJavaNetProject(StatsProperty.java:55)
        at hudson.plugins.javanet.StatsProperty.getJavaNetProject(StatsProperty.java:37)
        at hudson.plugins.javanet.StatsProperty.getJobAction(StatsProperty.java:28)
        at hudson.plugins.javanet.StatsProperty.getJobAction(StatsProperty.java:26)
        at hudson.model.JobProperty.getJobActions(JobProperty.java:133)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.createTransientActions(AbstractProject.java:758)
        at hudson.model.Project.createTransientActions(Project.java:213)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.updateTransientActions(AbstractProject.java:751)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.onLoad(AbstractProject.java:338)
        at hudson.model.Project.onLoad(Project.java:90)
        at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:276)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$18.run(Jenkins.java:2590)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:900)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Some Versions used:

```
jdk1.7.0_21
Jenkins ver. 1.549
CVS Plug-in 2.11
cvs-tag 1.7
```

EDIT 1:

I checked known issues related to the cvs plugin, and found this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18999
However, I couldn't successfully follow the proposed workaround. In the end I installed Jenkins CVS-Plugin v1.6, which seems to work more stable. (survives a jenkins restart, at least)

I did downgrade the plugin to version 1.6

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by you having the [Java.net plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Java.net+Plugin) installed. If you still need this then alter your jobs to manually specify the Java.net project name before upgrading the CVS plugin, otherwise uninstall the Java.net plugin and re-upgrade the CVS plugin.